# Tools to detect Memory leaks to a certain extent in reasonable timeframe

Tags: file, memory-leaks, profiling, tomcat6, java-5

Am looking for tools to detect Memory Leaks, File open issues in Java based applications written using Netbeans and deployed on Tomcat 6 without having to spend hours, something which can detect these anomalous behavior to a certain extent within a reasonable timeframe. 
Would appreciate if anyone provides recommendations around the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) successfully. It is simple to use and has pretty complete documentation.

Comment: You can use it independently of Eclipse.  Just give it a heap dump and away you go.